# Probability of finishing a course of treatment

Tags: conditional-probability

You need to take a medicine 1 x per day for 5 days.  What is the probability of completing the treatment expressed in terms of the probability of taking each dose given that the probability of taking a dose (other than the first dose) is conditional on having taken the prior dose.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  you have five tries in a row, all of which must succeed, with each having the same probability.